# Swap Wordpress "Widget Area" based on Page Template

Tags: php, wordpress, function, widget

i'm using 3 widget areas in my child theme's footer.

i created a secondary custom theme successfully, and am hoping i can simply change those 3 widget area's out in the second theme.

"**Footer - Column 1**" would change to "**Alt Footer - Column 1**"
"**Footer - Column 2**" would change to "**Alt Footer - Column 2**"
"**Footer - Column 3**" would change to "**Alt Footer - Column 3**"

*(and yes, i've already created in WP admin > Appearnace > Widgets, those 3 new custom widget areas, & put temp text widgets in them for now).*

i'm using this in "functions.php" to change the "**Menu**"...

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_args', 'respect_menu_swap' );
function respect_menu_swap( $args = '' ) 
{
    if(is_page_template('template-respect.php') && $args['menu_id'] == 'avia-menu') 
    {
        $args['menu'] = '16';
    } 
    return $args;
}
```

**...am hoping for something similar to change each of those "widget areas".**

i've searched, read, searched, & read a LOT trying to figure this out & just can't seem to grasp what should go in place of the menu terms in that code bit. i really struggle with PHP, so would greatly appreciate specific explanation & code:-)

and, i'm saying "**Widget Area**" *instead* of "**Widgets**" because i realized that "Widgets" are *INSIDE* the "Widget Areas". i'd like to swap the whole area instead of just the widget so my people can add/remove various widgets in those 3 "areas" in the WP > Appearance > Widgets admin page as needed. it’s my understanding that if i just use the “Widget ID” then when someone changes which widget(s) are in one of those widget areas, it won’t update on the sites front-end without me changing those ID’s first. i’d like to avoid having to do that if possible.

(BTW: i'm using the [Enfold](https://kriesi.at) WP theme, if that matters)

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to do? It sounds like you would just register another widget area and use it in your page template instead of the original one. If you're asking whether widget areas can be dynamically registered based on the page template, that would be no, because the page template does not load in the admin.

Comment: Or are you just trying to load pre-named widget areas based on the page template? I can add an answer based on that in case it helps.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH for the effort/offer, but i 'just' figured it out (after 'days' of head scratching). added answer below..

Comment: Ah, lol well I just posted an answer for what I thought you were talking about but nevermind then!

Answer (score 0):

WOW!
well, it would *seems* as tho i figured it out!

after MORE searching, i came across https://learn.wordpress.org/lesson-plan/widget-areas

apparently i had to "register" a "sidebar" - which thru me, as i was wanting to modify in the footer. after looking *that* up, the term "sidebar" is used anywhere the theme allows the user to add widgets in. and since the Enfold theme footer allows for widgets, i had to "register_sidebar" and THEN modify a line in the template.
i also didn't understand why i had to "register" the "widget area's" at all, thinking that just by creating the custom widgets in WP admin > Appearance > Widgets, that should do it, but no. ya gotta create them there and *ALSO* register them in the child functions too.

so after reading that wordpress page (linked above), i started hunting around in the main Enfold theme files, trying to find something similar. since apparently, some things are named differently than in other themes, which is why my copy/pasting of examples i found elsewhere didn't work.
i found it in... **`themes > enfold > includes > admin > register-widget-area.php`**

so i combined what that wordpress link offered with the footer widget registration and came up with this code that i put in my **child functions.php**...

```
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'MYWIDGETAREA' );
function MYWIDGETAREA() 
{
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => 'Respect Footer - Column ' . $i,
        'id'            => 'espect_foot_widget_' . $i,
        'before_widget' => '<section id="%1$s" class="widget clearfix %2$s">',
        'after_widget'  => '<span class="seperator extralight-border"></span></section>',
        'before_title'  => '<h3 class="widgettitle">',
        'after_title'   => '</h3>'
    ));
}
```

in the array, i only changed the "name" & "id", leaving the rest so the structure matches the original theme.

then i went to my **template-custom.php** and found this line...

```
if( ! ( function_exists( 'dynamic_sidebar' ) && dynamic_sidebar( 'Footer - Column ' . $i ) ) )
```

...and replaced it with...

```
if( ! ( function_exists( 'dynamic_sidebar' ) && dynamic_sidebar( 'Respect Footer - Column ' . $i ) ) )
```

AMAZING!!!

well hopefully all this may benefit someone else in a similar position some day.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a different widget area for each page template, you can just register a widget area for each one, since the page template would contain it.

But, if you're using the same footer file on multiple page templates and want to load different widget areas dynamically, you would first have to register widget areas with the page template slugs included in the ID, for example:

```
function custom_register_widget_area() {
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => 'Template Respect Footer',
        'id'            => 'template-respect-footer',
        'before_widget' => '<div class="widget">',
        'after_widget'  => '</div>',
        'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title'   => '</h2>',
    ) );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'custom_register_widget_area' );
```

Adding another `register_sidebar()` for each template.

Then in the footer file (using `template-respect.php` from your example) you can get the basename of the template to build the widget area ID:

```
$template = basename( get_page_template_slug( get_the_id() ), '.php' );

if ( $template && is_active_sidebar( $template . '-footer' ) ) {
    dynamic_sidebar( $template . '-footer' );
} elseif ( is_active_sidebar( 'default-footer' ) ) {
    dynamic_sidebar( 'default-footer' );
}
```

This would load whichever widget area matches the page template slug, or the default if the default page.php is being used.